# Spring webflux, testing `ServerResponse`

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-webflux

How can I test a *handler* method that receive `ServerRequest` and return `Mono<ServerResponse>` ?

I can create a `ServerRequest` via `org.springframework.mock.web.reactive.function.server.MockServerRequest.builder()`. And assert on the `ServerResponse.statusCode()`. However I would like to test the body of this `ServerResponse` but there is no way to extract it.

```
ServerResponse response = target.search(MockServerRequest.builder()
    .method(HttpMethod.GET)
    .build()
  ).block();

assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
//assertThat(response.body()).isNotNull();
```

I don't want to do a broader test with the `WebTestClient`, I would like to test all possible cases of response with unit tests.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it seems that the best solution is to use the `WebTestClient`. However this one can be used without a running server;

> The `spring-test` module includes a `WebTestClient` that can be used to test WebFlux server endpoints **with or without a running server**.
>
> -- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-tests

The trick is to use the `bindTo..()` builder method. In my case `bindToRouterFunction(new MyRouter(new MyHandler()))` works well

Comment: I thought you mentioned you don't want to do broader test with `WebTestClient`

Comment: And you are right. My concern was to keep test running quickly without starting the whole server. And, as I explain in my answer, `WebTestClient` can be used without a running server.

Comment: Is there a way to assert the `ServerResponse` without using the `WebTestClient` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not actively working with spring anymore. Thus I cannot give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same question, because I don't want to start the entire Spring context for every test. Thanks for the info in the own-answer, this helped me. Here is a complete example including Mockito and JUnit5:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UsersHandlerTest {
  @Mock
  UserRepository userRepository;

  WebTestClient client;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    UsersHandler usersHandler = new UsersHandler(userRepository);
    Router router = new Router(usersHandler);

    Mockito.when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(
      Arrays.asList("", ""));

    client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(router.getUsers()).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void getCommands() {
    client.get().uri("/users")
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
      .exchange()
      .expectStatus().isOk()
      .expectBody().json("{}");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956926/assert-webflux-serverresponse-using-mockserverrequest/67295863#67295863) insisting not to use WebTestClient.
I have ended up answering my own question after discovering that it is possible to cast the response to a type that allows inspecting body (entity).

The magic line (Kotlin) is:

```kotlin
(serverResponse as EntityResponse<Fleet>).entity()
```

---

**Edit:**
So for the case of expecting an empty body, you could do:

```kotlin
assert(serverResponse !is EntityResponse<*>)
```

Thanks for @andred for pointing this out

Comment: Be careful using this approach: It only works if a response entity is available. It doesn't work, if the ServerResponse-Builder is used to build a noContent- or notFound-Response. Always check types before casting.

Comment: You are right.
I have got a change to revisit this topic, so in the case where you expect no body (like in noContent), you could assert the opposite `assert(it !is EntityResponse<*>)`