# Assert WebFlux ServerResponse using MockServerRequest

Tags: unit-testing, spring-webflux

I want to separate router layer from handler layer, so I don't want to use `WebTestClient` as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893453/spring-webflux-testing-serverresponse). I do not think throwing `WebTestClient` at the problem is the right solution.

In my case, I am using `MockServerRequest`, which only allows testing for http status code and headers. There is no way to assert the body of the response.

```kotlin
val request = MockServerRequest.builder()
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri(URI.create("/service"))
            .build()

StepVerifier.create(myHandler.handleGet(request))
            .assertNext { /* and assertThat(it.body()) ...  */  }
            .verifyComplete()
```

Is there a way to assert the body? If none then why and what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, I have noticed that I can see the body (entity). Hence, I have inspected the returned class and its hierarchy. I have realized that casting may solve the problem, and it worked (I am not sure if it is the right way though).

For the code in question:

```kotlin
val request = MockServerRequest.builder()
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri(URI.create("/service"))
            .build()

StepVerifier.create(myHandler.handleGet(request))
            .assertNext { assertThat((it as EntityResponse<Fleet>).entity())
                              .isNotNull /* add more assertions */ }
            .verifyComplete()
```